# How to have a countdown in every TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to let each cell have its own "time left" by being able to set specific countdown times for each cell.

I have looked over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222004), and it is pretty much what I am trying to do, but instead of writing cell.expiryTimeInterval = 10, I would probably get the value from the datasource and have it correspond with the index.

First and foremost, I haven't gotten the timers from that answer to work. I've tried the `RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .common)`, and everything seems right. I couldn't comment on that thread because I don't have enough rep, so I'm making a new post.

Here's relevant portions of my custom cell class:

```
private var timer: Timer?
private var timeCounter: Double = 0

var expiryTimeInterval: TimeInterval? {
    didSet {
        startTimer()
    }
}

let timeLabel: UILabel = {
    let tl = UILabel()
    tl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
    tl.textColor = .black
    return tl
}()

func set(content: Item) {
    self.expiryTimeInterval = content.time
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupCell()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupCell()
}

private func startTimer() {
    if let interval = expiryTimeInterval {
        timeCounter = interval
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                          repeats: true,
                          block: { [weak self] _ in
                            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                return
                            }
                            strongSelf.onComplete()
            })
        } else {
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                          target: self,
                          selector: #selector(onComplete),
                          userInfo: nil,
                          repeats: true)
        }
    }
}

@objc func onComplete() {
    guard timeCounter >= 0 else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        return
    }
    timeLabel.text = String(format: "%d", timeCounter)
    timeCounter -= 1
}

func setupCell() {
    self.contentView.addSubview(timeLabel)
    let labelInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: -16, right: -16)
    let timeLabelConstraints = [
        timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: labelInsets.left),
        timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: labelInsets.top),
        timeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: labelInsets.right),
        timeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: labelInsets.bottom)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(stackViewConstraints)
}
```

"Item" is my model containing the `TimeInterval`

Comment: You don't want a timer per cell. You only need one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246

Comment: @Paulw11 I got the timer working for each cell after putting TimerModel in my datasource, but can you give some pointers on how to count down instead of up? I feel like it's a bit harder to work around. If not, then that's fine

Comment: I would suggest that instead of using a `Double` you should calculate the `Date` that corresponds to the end time.  You can then use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to calculate the number of seconds remaining.